# Execute Shell script without sudo password

Tags: shell, sudo

I have a shell script as given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u testuser -H sh -c "
mkdir /usr/local/testdir;
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Successfull";
else
    echo "Unsuccessfull";
fi
"
```

I have given privileges to user testuser to execute shell script with sudo, but without asking password.For this I add the below line in `/etc/sudoers` file,

```
testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And it works fine that, I could run commands with sudo, but without asking password. But the above shell script always giving out put ass follows,

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/testdir': Permission denied
Successfull
```

And it is not creating directory `testdir` inside `/usr/local`. Please advice me what modification shall I need to do to work this script fine.

Thanks.

Comment: ok, so as far as I can see this has nothing to do with sudo. Simply the user doesn't have the right to create the directory. Are you familiar with unix file permissions?

Comment: But, I can create directory in that location with command `sudo mkdir /usr/local/testdir`, that is without prompting password !

Comment: Note that you should restrict `NOPASSWD` sudo access to individual scripts only, otherwise anyone getting access to that user's account basically becomes root...

Comment: this question illustrates the difference between `sudo make-me-a-sandwich` vs `sudo -u honey make-me-a-sandwich`; the former will always succeed; the latter may or may not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1.) You told:

```
sudo -u testuser -H ...
```

what's mean: run the command as `testuser`, and he doesn't has permissions to write into the `/usr/local` therefore you getting `permission denied`.

When you remove the `-u testuser`, the command will run as root (as default) (without password for the `testuser`) and will create the directory.

Seems, you simply misunderstand how the `sudo` and `/etc/sudoers` works. The `-u user` mean

> -u user' The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user
>   other than root. To specify a uid instead of a user name, #uid.
>   When running commands as a uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a
>   backslash ('\'). Security policies may restrict uids
>   to those listed in the password database. The sudoers policy allows
>   uids that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw
>   option is not set. Other security policies may not support this.

2.) second problem the `Successfull` message.

You're using **double quotes** for `sh -c`. The `Variable expansion` is done **BEFORE** the `sh -c` even starts. So use single quotes, and will get the correct `Unsuccessfull` message:

```
sudo -u testuser -H sh -c '
mkdir /usr/local/testdir
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Successfull";
else
    echo "Unsuccessfull";
fi
'
```

and use the next as a solution:

```
sudo -H sh -c '
mkdir /usr/local/testdir
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    echo "Successfull";
else
    echo "Unsuccessfull";
fi
'
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. This worked for me. I am a very beginner in shell scripting. Need to learn lot.Thanks again.